# Changing Text with Timer

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to change the string of a text object after a number of seconds. This is the code:

```
  if scoretoShow then
aAscoretext = display.newText( scoretoShow.."/8", 200, 200, "Comic Sans MS", 30)
else
aAscoretext = display.newText( "0/8", 200, 200, "Comic Sans MS", 30)
end
aAscoretext:setFillColor( 0.4 )
aAscoretext.x = Letterbackground.x
aAscoretext.y = Letterbackground.y + Letterbackground.width/3


   if type(scoreChange) == "number" then
for f = 0, scoreChange, 1 do
    print("f")
        print(f)

timer.performWithDelay( timeforChange-(f*(timeforChange/scoreChange)), 
function()
 aAscoretext.text = "HELLO!"
Letterbackground:setFillColor( gradients[newScore-f+1] )
audio.play(Wobble)
end)
```

However, if I put the  `aAscoretext.text = "HELLO!"` just under `print(f)` then it works fine.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want the text aAscoretext to change to read HELLO! after the delay set by the timer. It doesn't do that. I want to know why not.

Comment: Two `end` statements are missing in the snippet (one to close the `for` block and another to close `if type(scoreChange) == "number" then`).

Answer (score 0):

All those calls to `timer.performWithDay()` in the `for` loop may not be executing the way you expect.  I find it easier to make the listener that changes the `text` property in the TextObject just call itself again after a delay if another step in the change is needed.

This will illustrate what I mean.  Let's say you have a TextObject `score` that displays the score and two variables `currentScore` and `newScore` where `newScore > currentScore` and both are integer values.  If you want the score display to "count up" from `currentScore` to `newScore`, you can do it this way:

```
local currentScore = 0 

--
-- Call this function when the score needs to change
--
local function newScoreToDisplay( newScore )    

    local countingInterval = 100 -- we want to add 1 to the displayed score every 100 ms

    local function adjustScoreDisplay( event )

       if currentScore < newScore then
           currentScore = currentScore + 1
           score.text = tostring( currentScore ) -- score is a Corona TextObject
           timer.performWithDelay( countingInterval, adjustScoreDisplay )
       end
    end

    -- First call to adjustScore() if score really needs adjusting
    if currentScore < newScore then
        timer.performWithDelay( 0, adjustScore ) --make the first change immediately
    end
end
```